# Report effort per work item in TFS 2012

Tags: reporting-services

I have sucessfully set up the reporting capability for my TFS 2012. Now I'd like to report effort per work item (like User Story). I'm using the Agile process template, so the tasks and user stories have a field for typing in effort. However, during report creation I can't idendify the table and colum where the effort resides. Can anyone give a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It's in the table FactCurrentWorkItem, field Microsoft_VSTS_Scheduling_CompletedWork.